# The Amazing Audio Engine AERecorder not recording

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio, ios6.0

I am using The Amazing Audio Engine class AERecorder to record audio from the built-in microphone. I have inspected the sample project that comes with the download. I have also implemented the code presented in the TAAE [documentation for using the AERecorder](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/doc/_receiving-_audio.html#Recording).

As far as I can tell, I have everything needed to record audio. Alas, the file is created, the header is there, but there is no audio data to be had. All I can figure is that there is something wrong with the AEAudioController or some setting in my Xcode project.

For reference, my project is using ARC, and I believe I followed the instructions in the documentation for adding the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flags to any sources imported.

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, how was it resolved?

I would have tried to ask this question on TAAE forum, but I am unable to sign up.

Here is the code for anyone not willing to following the link.

**EDIT: Code below is updated to show what detail was previously lacking.**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad]
   self.audioController = [[AEAudioController alloc] 
                       initWithAudioDescription:[AEAudioController nonInterleavedFloatStereoAudioDescription] 
                                   inputEnabled:YES];
   //************************
   // This is the crucial bit of code that was missing
   NSError *error;
   [audioController start:&error];
   //************************
}

- (void)beginRecording {
   // Init recorder
   self.recorder = [[AERecorder alloc] initWithAudioController:_audioController];
   NSString *documentsFolder = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) 
                               objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *filePath = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Recording.aiff"];
   // Start the recording process
   NSError *error = NULL;
   if ( ![_recorder beginRecordingToFileAtPath:filePath 
                                     fileType:kAudioFileAIFFType 
                                        error:&error] ) {
      // Report error
      return;
   }
   // Receive both audio input and audio output. Note that if you're using
   // AEPlaythroughChannel, mentioned above, you may not need to receive the input again.
   [_audioController addInputReceiver:_recorder];
   [_audioController addOutputReceiver:_recorder];
}
-(void)stopRecording
{
    [_recorder finishRecording];
    [_audioController removeInputReceiver:_recorder];
    [_audioController removeOutputReceiver:_recorder];
    self.recorder = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out the problem, which should have been obvious. I was not calling the `[audioController start:&error]` anywhere in my code. Now it works like a charm. Hope this helps someone. I have to say, this is some very good software.